# What is this 'pretend dialogue' technique called

Tags: style, technique, terminology, rhetoric

There's a style that is popular on blogs, and takes the form of a dialogue between the reader and the author, where the author provides both sides of the argument, like a ventriloquist. Often there's a tendency to write the reader's part as being less savvy or intelligent than the author.

### [Author], my method is better than yours because blah.

Actually it's not, and here's why.

### Woah, I never thought about it that way. But what about blah blah?

Excellent question. Here's the answer, blah blah.

### That's amazing! Thanks for enlightening me! Where can I learn more?

You're welcome! You can buy my book at blah blah.

---

Is there a term for this style, especially the self-complimentary aspect?

Comment: I have no idea, but don't use it, it's annoying.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The method of laying out ideas in the form of a dialogue where both speakers are written by one author is called **dialectic**. It has its roots in philosophy and has wide application.

What you're describing sounds like a *very poor example* of this technique. It uses the *form* of the dialectic method, but the content is more akin to the **FAQ** on a commercial website. It posits only the questions for which it has satisfactory answers, and so creates the apperance of a flawless system with no vulnerabilities.

It's a disingenuous form of argument, but quite popular.